# What is acceptable file name in Android when storing to SD card

Tags: android

I am getting following error when trying to save to external cache dir (SD card) :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException:
/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/myapp/cache/files/filenamexxx.png?1385609534:
open failed: EINVAL (Invalid argument) file:filenamexxx.png?1385609534
```

Using following code:

```
File sdCard = ctx.getExternalCacheDir();
File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/files/");
dir.mkdirs();
File file = new File(dir, mFileName);
fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
fos.write ....
```

But saving to device when no SD card found works fine:

```
fos = ctx.openFileOutput(mFileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write ....
```

Does the `?1385609534` in the file name end mess it up, when trying to save into SD cache?

Thanks.

Comment: the `?` is a reserved character. See this answer for further details http://stackoverflow.com/a/2703882/826657.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some filesystems dont allow certain characters. You can check out which filesystem cant use which character here:
[Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems)

In your case it is most likely FAT32, so:

> Any byte except for values 0-31, 127 (DEL) and: " * / : < > ? \ | + , . ; = [] (lowcase a-z are stored as A-Z). With VFAT LFN any Unicode except NUL

Answer (score 1):

I ended up replacing all illegal characters:

```
mFileName = mFileName.replaceAll("[|?*<\":>+\\[\\]/']", "_");
```