# trying to save a file with the current date and the name that the user choose but i get ERROR: open failed :EACCES (Permission denied )

Tags: android, runtime-error, fileoutputstream

i am trying to save a file in the emulator with the name that choose it the user and the current date .

but i get an error message that say :**open failed :EACCES  (Permission denied )**

how to fix this error i will appreciate any help

## SingInSActivity.java

```
public class SignSoldgerActivity extends Activity {

    EditText edit_txt_note;
    final Context context = this;
    // attribute for the date picker

    public String fileName;

    Button btn_save_soldger;
    TextView txtatePicker;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_soldger);

        edit_txt_note = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTxtNote);


        txtatePicker = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDate);




        btn_save_soldger = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSaveSoldger);
        btn_save_soldger.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // / for creating a dialog
                LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompts, null);

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        context);

                // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
                alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

                final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView
                        .findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);

                // set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int id) {
                                        // get user input and set it to result
                                        // edit text
                                        String userinputResult = userInput
                                                .getText().toString();

                                        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                                                "yyyy/MM/dd_HH:mm:ss");
                                        Date now = new Date();
                                        fileName = formatter.format(now) + "__"
                                                + userinputResult;

                                        txtatePicker.setText(fileName);
                                    }
                                })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int id) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });

                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();

                // / for saving the file on the SD

                try {
                    String sdPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            .getAbsolutePath() + fileName + ".txt";
                    File myFile = new File(sdPath);
                    myFile.createNewFile();
                    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
                    OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(
                            fOut);
                    // append or write
                    myOutWriter.append(edit_txt_note.getText());
                    myOutWriter.close();
                    fOut.close();
                    edit_txt_note.setText("");
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                            "Done Writing SD" + fileName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

        });
    }
```

the permission is added in the

## manifest file

**`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`**

Comment: Have you created SD card size in AVD creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Emulator SD Card size should be defined

You need to edit your `AVD` to allot an SD card size to it. You need to launch the AVD Manager dor it of course.

Here's the screen where you add it:

[image: Edit AVD]

### Updating after to include your comments

You're mostly missing the path seperator.

```
String sdPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
    .getAbsolutePath() + fileName + ".txt";
```

must be changed to

```
String sdPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
    .getAbsolutePath() +"/"+ fileName + ".txt";
```

Comment: i am using the genymotion emulator and this is the specifications of the emulator **Memory Size:2048 MB**, **android version 4.3**, **Data storage capacity: 16384 MB**

Comment: I've not used genymotion before. I'd wager that data storage capacity is for internal storage. Their docs/manuals may yield more information.

Comment: i tried now on the avd of the google and create an avd with SD size 40 MB and when i tried to start   and save the file an new error had appear : **Open failed : EROFS (Read-only file system)**

Comment: Please open a new question for the new error you have. I'm guessing you are trying to write somewhere on the FS where you don't have write perms. Accept/upvote my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Please add following in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Most likely you need to read as well so this is needed for that:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Also note that most likely SD card has different allowed characters so you might need to replace all `"|\\?*<\":>+[]/'";` with wanted character like `_`

Comment: What is the filename you are trying to write? Could there be illegal characters?

Comment: the user choose the file name  after an alert dialog pop up and ask him to enter a file name then the system will add **2 under Score**  to the name and  the current date and time that has a format **"yyyy/MM/dd_HH:mm:ss"**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679699/what-characters-allowed-in-file-names-on-android You can see from here which are allowed characters.