# Restrictions on file names in internal storage?

Tags: android, file

Are there any restrictions on what is an acceptable String for the name of a file in an Android app's internal storage? I have found that you are not allowed to use the file separator character. Are there any other disallowed characters, or restrictions on the length of the String?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What characters allowed in file names on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679699/what-characters-allowed-in-file-names-on-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will generally follow unix style filesystem conventions. Most Android devices are now using ext4 format on flash media for internal storage. Originally yaffs2 was being used or even  ubi/ubifs. But most OEMs have shifted to ext4.