# Negative random int when new File is created with File.createTempFile()

Tags: java, android

I have a Android app that uses the Android camera app. Because I need the specific file name, I created my own CameraActivity.

In this activity I create my temp file like so:

```
public File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    File pathOfStorageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    pathOfStorageDir.mkdir();

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String filePrefix = "img_" + timeStamp + "_";
    String suffix = ".jpg";

    File image = File.createTempFile(filePrefix, suffix, pathOfStorageDir);
    currentFileName = image.getName();
    currentFilePath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

The weird thing is that I get sometimes negative values from in the new file name.

As I saw `createTempFile()` calls `generateTempFile()` and that method should create a **random absolute int**. Why is this random int sometimes negative? Or how can I avoid that?

**The problem:** I need the file later in my app but can't import it with a "-" sign. That throws me this exception:
`Error:com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceException: <package-name>/app/src/main/res/drawable/img_sfr_20170715_-1‌​13604.jpg: Error: '-' is not a valid file-based resource name character: File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or underscore`

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Why does it matter? Is there a specific problem it causes, or is it merely aesthetically unpleasing?

Comment: @Andy Turner: The "-" sign is not accepted as character for a file name in Android. So I always have to rename the names.

Comment: @HansiHansenbaum Sure it is.  Android is Linux.  The only unacceptable characters are / and null terminators

Comment: @HansiHansenbaum https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679699/what-characters-allowed-in-file-names-on-android

Comment: Thanks for the help, guys. But I don't get it, why do I get this error then?

`Error:com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceException: <package-name>/app/src/main/res/drawable/img_sfr_20170715_-113604.jpg: Error: '-' is not a valid file-based resource name character: File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or underscore`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is interesting: It seems the File.createTempFile() method in android.jar is implemented differently than the one in rt.jar.

**In rt.jar (with Java 8), we have:**

```
public static File createTempFile(String prefix, String suffix,
                                  File directory)
    throws IOException
{
    if (prefix.length() < 3)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Prefix string too short");
    if (suffix == null)
        suffix = ".tmp";

    File tmpdir = (directory != null) ? directory
                                      : TempDirectory.location();
    SecurityManager sm = System.getSecurityManager();
    File f;
    do {
        f = TempDirectory.generateFile(prefix, suffix, tmpdir);

        if (sm != null) {
            try {
                sm.checkWrite(f.getPath());
            } catch (SecurityException se) {
                // don't reveal temporary directory location
                if (directory == null)
                    throw new SecurityException("Unable to create temporary file");
                throw se;
            }
        }
    } while ((fs.getBooleanAttributes(f) & FileSystem.BA_EXISTS) != 0);

    if (!fs.createFileExclusively(f.getPath()))
        throw new IOException("Unable to create temporary file");

    return f;
}
```

which uses `TempDirectory.generateFile(String, String, File)`:

```
    private static final SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    static File generateFile(String prefix, String suffix, File dir)
        throws IOException
    {
        long n = random.nextLong();
        if (n == Long.MIN_VALUE) {
            n = 0;      // corner case
        } else {
            n = Math.abs(n);
        }

        // Use only the file name from the supplied prefix
        prefix = (new File(prefix)).getName();

        String name = prefix + Long.toString(n) + suffix;
        File f = new File(dir, name);
        if (!name.equals(f.getName()) || f.isInvalid()) {
            if (System.getSecurityManager() != null)
                throw new IOException("Unable to create temporary file");
            else
                throw new IOException("Unable to create temporary file, " + f);
        }
        return f;
    }
```

This will lead to file names with positive random numbers in them.

**In android.jar (Android API 20), we have:**

```
public static File createTempFile(String prefix, String suffix, File directory)
        throws IOException {
    // Force a prefix null check first
    if (prefix.length() < 3) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("prefix must be at least 3 characters");
    }
    if (suffix == null) {
        suffix = ".tmp";
    }
    File tmpDirFile = directory;
    if (tmpDirFile == null) {
        String tmpDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir", ".");
        tmpDirFile = new File(tmpDir);
    }
    File result;
    do {
        result = new File(tmpDirFile, prefix + tempFileRandom.nextInt() + suffix);
    } while (!result.createNewFile());
    return result;
}
```

Since `tempFileRandom` is a standard `Random` instance, its `nextInt()` method will return positive as well as negative integers.

Thus, using `File.createTempFile()` can return file names with minus signs / hyphens on Android.

The best option, therefore, would be to implement your own file name generator and `createTempFile()` method, based on the one provided in the runtime library, but with positive random numbers only.

Comment: So it's a bug in Android. Its own code generates filenames which it cannot use.

Comment: As stated in other comments, Android in general - being Linux based - can handle file names with minus signs in them. It seems to be a problem with a file name limitation in the build process, judging from Hansenbaum's error message: Error:com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceException. Admittedly, creating a temporary file and then adding it as a resource is a bit unusual.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I think I let this one slide. My goal was to implement a temporary solution to save and add image files to the prototype. But on a long term basis, I will have to find a network based solution anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For an easy workaround, you could just replace "-" with something like "x" in the filename string.

Strictly speaking, this could "void the warranty" about createFileExclusively(), but the possibility of a race/collision is almost non-existent here.