# Use email address as file name in Android

Tags: java, android, email, filenames

Due to some requirement I want to save text files files to Android's file system and read it anytime programmatically.

For each user who will be using the *same* phone there will be a different text file stored. Unfortunately, at that time when the user has not logged in the only unique information about the user I have is the email address (or is there anything else?).

So my question is can I use the email address as the filename for these .txt files such as `"xyz_123@email.com.txt"` since the email address can have multiple special characters which I'm not sure are allowed in filenames?

Comment: There is no problem. Just save using email but dont miss the .txt at the end!

Comment: I don't think it will work in all cases.  There are characters allowed in email addresses that are not allowed in file names.  You might be better computing a hash from the email and storing that as the file name.

Comment: You should be ok (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679699/what-characters-allowed-in-file-names-on-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this .

**1.create**

```
String email = "xyz_123@email.com";
File file = new File(email + ".txt");
if (!file.exists()) {
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
Log.e("FILE_NAME", file.getName());
```

**2.Add permission**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**3.And you could use https://github.com/permissions-dispatcher/PermissionsDispatcher to request permission .**