# Can't open a file which has a question mark in its name

Tags: java, android, file

In my Android app, users can download files. The app modify the downloaded file right after the download completes. However, whenever the downloaded file's name includes a question mark somewhere in it, the downloaded file cannot be reached and thus cannot be modified. Related code is as follows:

```
String pathToFile = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/" + document.getTitle();

// Example pathToFile: /storage/emulated/0/Download/Recording ? 20171227.mp3
File downloadedFile = new File(pathToFile);

if (!downloadedFile.exists()) {
    // Always gets here if filename includes at least one '?'
}
```

I try adding "file://" prefix to `pathToFile`, converting `pathToFile` to Uri or URI, but nothing worked. It always says file doesn't exist. Any help is appreciated.

**ADDITIONAL INFO:** The document filename is retrieved from the internet and I save the document using the same filename. I can see the file with same filename in the Downloads folder, however, I cannot open it programmatically.

Comment: Are you downloading this file yourself? If so, why not create it using a safe filename, one without spaces and odd punctuation?

Comment: Yeah, I do the download in the app itself. The DownloadManager manages to download and save it, so I did't want to impose any restriction.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679699/what-characters-allowed-in-file-names-on-android

Comment: @GriffeyDog, I checked the link before but it confused me since there is no single solution.

Comment: @CommonsWare, what do you recommend?

Comment: @Mehmed `?` is not generally supported in filenames, so you need to sanitize the filenames so they don't include `?`s.

Comment: I agree with GriffeyDog -- use safe filenames.

Comment: OK, I will, thanks. Do you know the minimal reserved/forbidden character set for providing safeness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As recommended by commentators, I replace `#`, `%` and `?` with empty string. The following characters don't cause a problem: `!@$^&*()[]{}|`