# logback-android FileAppender not creating files

Tags: android, logback, fileappender

I'm using [logback-android](https://github.com/tony19/logback-android) in a Kotlin project to generate logs in a file. I previously tested this solution in different Android versions without any issue, but I discovered an issue in Android 5.1: the parent directories to the log file are created but not the log files. How do I fix this?

*build.gradle:*

```
implementation 'io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging:1.6.24'
implementation 'com.github.tony19:logback-android:2.0.0'
```

*logback.xml:*

```xml
<configuration>
    <property name="LOG_DIR" value="${EXT_DIR:-${DATA_DIR}}/log.log" />
    <timestamp key="datetime" datePattern="yyyy'-'MMdd'-'HH':'mm':'ss"/>
    <appender name="logcat" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.android.LogcatAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>[%d{yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss}][%thread][%-5level][%logger{36}][%msg]%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="filelog" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_DIR}/${datetime}.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>[%d{yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss}][%thread][%-5level][%logger{36}][%msg]%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_DIR}/%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>5</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>500MB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="logcat" />
    </root>
    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="filelog" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hi Ernesto Garcia, and welcome to Stack Overflow! When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck!

Comment: Dependency issue should be publish in the github

Comment: @ErnestoGarcia Can you provide a link to a GitHub repo that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Thanks guys and sorry to answer so late. I think that I found the error reading the logs, apparently the patter used was the problem `"yyyy'-'MMdd'-'HH':'mm':'ss"` have the character `:` and in the 5.1 version of Android this patter represent some kind of issue

Comment: I created [this](https://github.com/egordunez/kotlinlogginglogbackandroid) example to reproduce the error

Answer (score 0):

*I recommend using `logback`'s [debug](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#dumpingStatusData) (e.g., `<configuration debug="true">` in `logback.xml`) to see helpful messages in `logcat` for troubleshooting.*

#### Android 5.1

`logcat` messages show that the filename is invalid. Specifically, Android 5.1 [disallows `:` in filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679699/what-characters-allowed-in-file-names-on-android) (not an issue in later versions of Android):

```html
<timestamp key="datetime" datePattern="yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss"/> <!-- DON'T USE COLONS IN ANDROID 5.1 -->
<file>${LOG_DIR}/${datetime}.log</file>
```

The problem would appear in `logcat` as a `FileNotFoundException`, as a [result of `FileOutputStream` failing to create the file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29):

```
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[filelog] - File property is set to [/storage/sdcard/logfolder/2019-09-07-05:22:42.log]
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard/logfolder/2019-09-07-05:22:42.log: open failed: EINVAL (Invalid argument)

...

|-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[filelog] - openFile(/storage/sdcard/logfolder/2019-09-07-05:22:42.log,true) failed
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard/logfolder/2019-09-07-05:22:42.log: open failed: EINVAL (Invalid argument)

...

|-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[filelog] - Attempted to append to non started appender [filelog].
```

The workaround is to remove the colons from the `RollingFileAppender`'s `file` property, while taking care to avoid any possible filename collisions with `fileNamePattern`. For example:

```html
<timestamp key="datetime" datePattern="yyyy-MM-dd--HHmmss"/>
<file>${LOG_DIR}/${datetime}.log</file>
...
<fileNamePattern>${LOG_DIR}/%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
```

#### Android 6+

Since `:` is allowed in filenames in Android 6+, we don't need to worry about filename collisions mentioned above. The config could stay the same.

Also, make sure to [request user permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) to write to external storage, or else `logback-android` will fail to create any parent directories to the destination file (and be missing write-access to the file itself). If debug is enabled, you'd see `logcat` messages like this:

```
|-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[filelog] - Failed to create parent directories for [/storage/emulated/0/logfolder/2019-09-07-02:27:04.log]
|-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[filelog] - openFile(/storage/emulated/0/logfolder/2019-09-07-02:27:04.log,true) failed
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/logfolder/2019-09-07-02:27:04.log: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

In your case, the permission requesting code should be in `onCreate()` of `MainActivity.kt` *before* logging anything that would cause writing to external storage:

```
import android.Manifest
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat

...

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), 1)
    }

    logger.info { "hello world" }
}
```