# remove reserved characters from a string in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679699/what-characters-allowed-in-file-names-on-android) that `"|\\?*<\":>+[]/'"` are reserved characters. How do I remove these characters from a string and replace them with `-`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use *replaceAll* function to replace all similar characters to other characters of your choice. For eg:

```
void main() {
  String s="afas//f/saqhr";
  s=s.replaceAll("/","-");// replacing all / to -
  print(s);
}
```

Comment: Do I have to check for each reserved character and then replace them with other character using `replaceAll()`?  Is there any other optimal solution that does the job in one go?

Comment: one solution is to add all reserved character in a list .Then iterate each character using a for loop and try to replace them. It's the only way then. Hope it helps.

Comment: Clearly not the only way, as illustrated by the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

For reusability's sake, I've created a [Dart package](https://pub.dev/packages/safe_filename).

To use it:

1. [Install](https://pub.dev/packages/safe_filename/install)
2. Use the encode function as follows:

```
import 'package:safe_filename/safe_filename.dart' as SafeFilename;

void main() {
 String veryUnsafeFilename = 'File?Name<152.file';
 String safeFilename = (SafeFilename.encode(veryUnsafeFilename, onlyAlphanumeric: true, separator: '-', lowercase: true));
 print(safeFilename); // file-name-152.file
}
```